# mbedtls websocket client library

Tags: ubuntu, websocket, mbedtls

I want to use mbedtls library for use as a websocket client on Ubuntu.

Can someone point me to some low footprint wrapper library as it appears that mbedtls itself does not support websockets client out of the box. My server is a node.js implementation. I want a minimal C library to connect to it over websockets.